# Inserting an image in PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I'm trying to insert an image into this piece of code.
This is the header from my website.

```
$headerNavigation['Home'] = array(
'link_url'      => coreFunctions::getCoreSitePath() . '/account_home.' . SITE_CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION,
'link_text'     => t ('Your_Files', 'Your Files'),
'user_level_id' => range(1, 20),
'position'      => 30
```

I've tried this:

```
$headerNavigation['Home'] = array(
'link_url'      => coreFunctions::getCoreSitePath() . '/account_home.' . SITE_CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION,
'link_text'     => t ('Your_Files', '<img src="path/to/my/img"> Your Files'),
'user_level_id' => range(1, 20),
'position'      => 30
```

Also tried this:

```
$headerNavigation['Home'] = array(
'link_url'      => coreFunctions::getCoreSitePath() . '/account_home.' . SITE_CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION,
'link_text'     => t ('Your_Files', echo '<img src="path/to/my/img"> Your Files'),
'user_level_id' => range(1, 20),
'position'      => 30
```

And also tried this:

```
$headerNavigation['Home'] = array(
'link_url'      => coreFunctions::getCoreSitePath() . '/account_home.' . SITE_CONFIG_PAGE_EXTENSION,
'link_text'     => t ('Your_Files', ?> '<img src="path/to/my/img"> Your Files'), <?php
'user_level_id' => range(1, 20),
'position'      => 30
```

But none of these seem to work.

Comment: Have no idea what `t()` does, but example 1 & 2 is most likely to work. But, there is no context, there is no way to be sure about anything...

Comment: Also "But none of these seem to work." doesn't really say much. You don't show how you are trying to use this array or what the output of the array is using `print_r` or similar.

Comment: if `t()` doesn't `return` a value, then that part will not produce anything, but again, no idea what that does...

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what u mean, I really don't know much about PHP, this is just the code in a website script I'm using.
I'm trying to add an image left of the link this code places on my website, The link is: Your Files.
When I use the echo function, I get a blank page, the other attempts just showed the raw text (<img src="path/to/my/img"> Your Files) as the link.
I don't know what the t ( ) function is.

Comment: Well you are using a function named `t` here `t ('Your_Files', '<img src="path/to/my/img"> Your Files')`, what does that function do?

Comment: I don't know what the 't' function does, if I remove the 't' I get a blank page.

Comment: Yeah blank page means you have a fatal error, probably syntax error at that point. What framework or web app (Wordpress, etc..) are you using? Unfortunately, with what you have provided, there is no way to just tell what is wrong.

Comment: Plain HTML, JS, & PHP. Not sure what more I could provide, I can't seem to find where the `t` is coming from.

Comment: You will need to download all the files for the site then do a search, through whatever method you have at your disposal, each page for `function t` or `t (` or `t(` or whatever to find where the site has defined that function. Then you need to show where this array is being used on your page.

Comment: t() is a function. This specific function is used in the translation and the second parameter is the default value.

Comment: Can you post the function code? Also can you post how `$headerNavigation` is used on the page?

Comment: It is used calling the php file with `require_once` .
Let me see where I can find the function code.